# Performing pairwise comparisons for chi-squred test in SPSS

Tags: spss, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have an independent variable (that is a group of 5; could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) and a dependent variable (that is categorical;  could be either Yes or No). I've run a chi-squred test and found significance. How can I run pairwise comparisons between the individual groups (group 1 vs. group 2, group 1 vs. 3) to get the significance between groups.

In other words, I am looking for something similar to ANOVA's post hoc Tukey's, except for chi-squared.